# npm-watch Sub Folders

Tags: npm, nodemon

I'm using [npm-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-watch) to watch my files for changes however it's only working on js files immediately in my src folder and not in any subfolders.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dla",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src\\index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env"
    ]
  },
  "watch": {
    "build": "src/*.js" <---HERE
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "npm-watch": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
  }
}
```

The documentation isn't very detailed on how to do this. From the documentation it states:

```
This module does very little but run nodemon for you, all credit for the reliable file watching and process restarting should go to there.
```

So perhaps I can accomplish this with nodemon. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the glob pattern to use the double glob stars (`**`) as follows:

```json
"watch": {
  "build": "src/**/*.js"
},
```

This glob pattern; `src/**/*.js`, will find all `.js` files in the `src/` directory and sub-directories of the `src/` directory (many levels deep).